# Break out from For loop in List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to below code in line, and looks like List comprehension doesn't support break.

Just trying to see if there is anyway we can implement below code in one line.

Basically if commonprefix is an empty list then I want to break out from the code otherwise implement the other logic in the code.

```
resp ={'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'Z6FCCH9V8NRRBXRQ', 'HostId': 'wNpjpou0pQHSiADh2wmkD6LpcWwlrZz7qN8o/PJFgfwZncArpNEbpuJW9gMYK7VL4ZAScBfxMKo=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'wNpjpou0pQHSiADh2wmkD6LpcWwlrZz7qN8o/PJFgfwZncArpNEbpuJW9gMYK7VL4ZAScBfxMKo=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'Z6FCCH9V8NRRBXRQ', 'date': 'Fri, 04 Aug 2023 10:22:09 GMT', 'x-amz-bucket-region': 'ap-southt-1', 'content-type': 'application/xml', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'IsTruncated': False, 'Marker': '', 'Name': 'bucket-19', 'Prefix': 'ABC/', 'Delimiter': '/', 'MaxKeys': 1000, 'CommonPrefixes': [{'Prefix': 'ABC/Test1/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test2/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test3/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test4/'}], 'EncodingType': 'url'}

if [x for x in resp["CommonPrefixes"]] ==[None]:
    break
test =  [re.search(r"/(\w+)", x["Prefix"]).group() for x in resp.search("CommonPrefixes")]
print(test)
```

Comment: you cannot break in a list comprehension. Stop thinking of list comprehensions as "one line for loops". They are constructs for expressing **mapping/filtering operations to create a list**. And stop trying to make your code "one line" to begin with.

Comment: Note, `[x for x in resp["CommonPrefixes"]]` is totally pointless. You just want `list(resp["CommonPrefixes"])`, and note, that will never equal `[None]`... this code doesnt make any sense

Comment: Start with `if resp["CommonPrefixes"]:` to test if the list is not empty.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the end result should be, but `itertools.takewhile` might be useful. You can wrap an iterable in that, setting a condition which makes the iteration stop: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile

Answer (score 0):

I used an if test like that :

Use case 1 with existing field :

```
import re
resp ={'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'Z6FCCH9V8NRRBXRQ', 'HostId': 'wNpjpou0pQHSiADh2wmkD6LpcWwlrZz7qN8o/PJFgfwZncArpNEbpuJW9gMYK7VL4ZAScBfxMKo=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'wNpjpou0pQHSiADh2wmkD6LpcWwlrZz7qN8o/PJFgfwZncArpNEbpuJW9gMYK7VL4ZAScBfxMKo=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'Z6FCCH9V8NRRBXRQ', 'date': 'Fri, 04 Aug 2023 10:22:09 GMT', 'x-amz-bucket-region': 'ap-southt-1', 'content-type': 'application/xml', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'IsTruncated': False, 'Marker': '', 'Name': 'bucket-19', 'Prefix': 'ABC/', 'Delimiter': '/', 'MaxKeys': 1000, 'CommonPrefixes': [{'Prefix': 'ABC/Test1/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test2/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test3/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test4/'}], 'EncodingType': 'url'}
field="CommonPrefixes"
if field in resp :
    test =  [re.search(r"/(\w+)", x["Prefix"]).group() for x in resp[field]] 
    print(test)
```

**['/Test1', '/Test2', '/Test3', '/Test4']**

Use case 2 with no existing field :

```
import re
resp ={'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'Z6FCCH9V8NRRBXRQ', 'HostId': 'wNpjpou0pQHSiADh2wmkD6LpcWwlrZz7qN8o/PJFgfwZncArpNEbpuJW9gMYK7VL4ZAScBfxMKo=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'wNpjpou0pQHSiADh2wmkD6LpcWwlrZz7qN8o/PJFgfwZncArpNEbpuJW9gMYK7VL4ZAScBfxMKo=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'Z6FCCH9V8NRRBXRQ', 'date': 'Fri, 04 Aug 2023 10:22:09 GMT', 'x-amz-bucket-region': 'ap-southt-1', 'content-type': 'application/xml', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'IsTruncated': False, 'Marker': '', 'Name': 'bucket-19', 'Prefix': 'ABC/', 'Delimiter': '/', 'MaxKeys': 1000, 'CommonPrefixes': [{'Prefix': 'ABC/Test1/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test2/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test3/'}, {'Prefix': 'ABC/Test4/'}], 'EncodingType': 'url'}
field="CommonPrefixes_other"
if field in resp :
    test =  [re.search(r"/(\w+)", x["Prefix"]).group() for x in resp[field]] 
    print(test)
```

** {nothing is printed} **

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: you can't use `break` or similar methods to get out of the loop of a comprehension. However, you can make use of tools like `itertools.takewhile`, whose predicate can be used similar to a `break` under a conditional statement.

To use a very simple example, suppose you have this loop you want to express as a comprehension:

```py
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

results = []
for item in items:
    if item == 6:
        break
    results.append(item)
print(results)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can do something like this using `itertools.takewhile`:

```py
from itertools import takewhile
results = [i for i in takewhile(lambda item: item != 6, items)]
print(results)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

That said, there's some good advice in the comments of your question that may help you achieve the result you're looking for without using a comprehension.